# Interconnected pytest fixtures: Varying test data in the lowest tier of fixtures

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I want to know if I am using the right approach in the situation described below:

I often find myself in the situation that I have some basic data (usually panda dataframes) I want to transform and derive some specialiced aspects from. Those aspects are computed once (since those operations can be quite costly) and are fed into the methods that need them (here `method_to_test`).

If I want to test those methods, I need the `basic data` and some fixtures `aspect1` and `aspect2` which work on `basic_data`. A very contrived example:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def basic_data:
   data = ['some', 'test', 'data']
   yield data

@pytest.fixture
def aspect1(basic_data):
    yield basic_data[-1]

@pytest.fixture
def aspect2(basic_data):
    yield len(basic_data)

def test_something(aspect1, aspect2):
    result = method_to_test(aspect1 ,aspect2)
    assert result == 'data3'

def method_to_test(a, b)
    return a + str(b)
```

I need this exact chain of aspects working on some data, but I want the `basic_data` to vary from test to test. Since I can't parameterize fixtures (as far as I know), in a naive approach I would have to duplicate these fixtures `basic_data`, `aspect1` and `aspect2` for every test with different `basic_data`.

The way I found to avoid this is to use fixtures to return a parameterizable function to return the aspects:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def test_data:
   def f(data):
       return [data[-1], len(data)]
   yield f

def test_something(test_data):
    aspect1, aspect2 = test_data(['some', 'other', 'test', 'data'])    
    result = method_to_test(aspect1 ,aspect2)
    assert result == 'data4'

def method_to_test(a, b)
    return a + str(b)
```

Is this the right approach? Are there better (or other, equally good) ways? Am I missing something?

Comment: You can parametrize fixtures. `@pytest.fixture(params=['some', 'test', 'data']) def basic_data(request): yield request.param`

Comment: For more on parametrizing fixtures: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#fixture-parametrize